# Как заблокировать всплывание клавиатуры в элементе EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

При уставновке фокуса в EditText, на экране появляется клавиатура. Как реализовать её блокировку (убрать всплывание)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Сам уже нашёл.
Нужно установить свойство:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```